# ENTER to TAB redirect problem: submit form at the end of cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this jQuery function to jumping on "input" styled components of the form:

```
$('*').live("keydown", function(e) 
{    
  var inputs = $(this).parents("form").eq(0).find(".input:visible:enabled"); 
  var idx = inputs.index(this); 

  // ENTER IS PRESSED
  if (e.keyCode == 13) 
  { 
    if (idx == inputs.length - 1) 
    {
      inputs[idx + 1].select();
    } 
    else 
    {                           
      inputs[idx + 1].focus(); 
      inputs[idx + 1].select();
    }
    return false;
  }
  // TAB IS PRESSED
  if (e.keyCode == 9) 
  { 
    inputs[idx + 1].select();
    return false;
  }
});
```

and this components on the form (reduced code):

```
<h:inputText id="persId" tabindex="1" styleClass="input">
<h:selectOneMenu id="type" tabindex="1" styleClass="input">
<h:selectOneMenu id="no" tabindex="1" styleClass="input">
<h:commandButton type="submit" tabindex="2" id="btnSubmit" styleClass="btninput"/>
```

what I need is to jumping on 3 inputs and after that submit a form (using Enter). When I replace selectOneMenu by inputText, it works fine, but with selectOneMenu, it doesn´t.

TAB rotate all three components normally.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE:** perhaps it would be enough to fire enter normally `if (idx == inputs.length - 1)`, but I don´t know how..?

**SOLVED:** aha, it's simple, just add `document.getElementById('food:btnSubmit').click();` :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved:** just fire submit button if appropriate conditions are performed

```
 .....
 if (e.keyCode == 13) 
 { 
   if (idx == inputs.length - 1) 
   {
     document.getElementById('formId:buttonId').click();
   }
 }
 .....
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't a page for the internet.  It's not smart to interfere with browser default behaviour.

Have you tried just returning true instead of false if they were on the last input?

Comment: No, it's intranet only. Redirecting of enter or F1-Fx is basic requirement of users. The true causes jump to first input, I don´t know why. But I've found another solution (updated my answer). It's not much elegant, but works :) anyway, thank you!

Comment: OK, the click() solution will work in some browsers (it's a Microsoft  creation).  That might be fine for your intranet.  Alternatively you can get the form and call submit() directly, but this will bypass any onsubmit event handlers you have.

Comment: And how could I call submit directly? Like this.form.submit();? But If I understand you well, you're right, because action on submit button is bypassed..